# Using a bean from the abstract configuration class in a configuration class imported in the class implementing the abstract one

Tags: java, spring, configuration, autowired

I have an abstract configuration class **Abs** that is implemented by **Impl**

**Abs** has a bean **ImportantBean**

We import a **Imprt** config. class to **Impl** and I need to use the **ImportantBean** in **Imprt**

How can I do that?

IntelliJ says it cannot be autowired

something like:

```
@Configuration 
@Import(Imprt.class)
public class Impl extends Abs {}

@Configuration
public abstract class Abs{
  @Bean
  public ImportantBean importantBean(){
  return new ImportantBean();}
}

@Configuration
public class Imprt{
  @Autowired
  private ImportantBean importantBean;
}
```

Comment: is there code to look at?

Comment: Sorry I cannot post the exact code. I'll write some sample

Comment: could you please add that to the question instead?

Comment: This should work. Please create a [mcve] demonstrating that it's failing.

Comment: An abstract configuration class doesn't make a lot of sense to me, you can't have multiple implementation since you can only declare the bean once. Please explain why you need this?

Comment: I can run this code in Eclipse Oxygen. I dont see any errors in IntelliJ. What is the error you got exactly?

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope The whole app is composed of many standalones that share the same abstract config for each app's context configuration class

Comment: @ShankarPS works but gives this https://ibb.co/eCXY1H

Comment: https://github.com/vitalieb/springContexts

Comment: Still you can use a normal AtConfiguration (At means @) class and import it with AtImport in each of the standalones without needing an abstract class and it makes a lot more sense this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Imprt` configuration class has no idea while autowiring as to where to get `ImportantBean` from. You also cannot ensure that when application context is built and beans have been loaded in Spring container *(I am assuming you are using Spring framework)*, `ImportantBean` should already be present before building `Imprt`

For configuration class `Imprt` to receive `ImportantBean`,

you need to @Import `Impl` class to `Imprt`, the code should be implemented like illustrated below-

```
@Configuration
// @Import(Imprt.class) --> removed this
public class Impl extends Abs {}

@Configuration
public abstract class Abs{
  @Bean
  public ImportantBean importantBean(){
  return new ImportantBean();}
}

@Configuration
@Import(Impl.class) // ---> added new import here
public class Imprt{
  @Autowired
  private ImportantBean importantBean;
}
```

Comment: Context is initialized by Impl and if I use your solution there will be no Imprt info in the app

Comment: @Vitalie Why don't you initialise the context with `Imprt.class`? What do you mean by import info? Your `Imprt.class` has all configuration which can initialise all other configuration which are imported to your Application.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration 
@Import(Imprt.class)
public class Impl extends Abs {}

@Configuration
public abstract class Abs{
  @Bean
  public ImportantBean importantBean(){
  return new ImportantBean();}
}


public class Imprt{
  @Autowired
  private ImportantBean importantBean;
}
```

Try removing the @Configuration in class `Imprt`. I don't know what Imprt does, but if it isn't a configuration, do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you created important Bean as private.

If You add new @Autowired importantBean in Impl class it will work although IntelliJ will mark it as error.

I am not sure, but I think changing private to protected should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works [github.com/vitalieb/springContexts](http://github.com/vitalieb/springContexts)
The problem was with Intellij not understanding which context config to use as main.
So the only thing that had to be done was to add the right context as the main context in Intellij.

[image]

Comment: Does that mean every person who clones your codebase will have to make this setting explicitly?

Comment: Code works without the setting too - but if you add this setting IntelliJ will not show errors